# First Larger-Scale Web Dev Project - Advice for Content Management?

Tags: php, sql, html, content-management-system

I'm familiar with HTML, CSS, and some PHP and Javascript. I've made several fairly complicated websites for which I've acted as webmaster, manually adding all content in HTML.

I'm about to put in a proposal for my first outside client at a larger business. They have an IT person that would be responsible for updating the website that I create for them.

My question is what to do about content management. I've looked into things like Drupal, but they seem overly complex for this kind of situation, with a single person adding updates of things like text, images, and PDFs.

What would you recommend as the next step above the simple way of manually uploading files and editing HTML like I'm used to? Something like a MySQL database and PHP calls? Would I then store all the images in the database as well?

I guess I'm just trying to figure out what's most common at a medium-sized business. I appreciate any guidance you can offer!

Nathaniel

Answer (score 1):

My company has built large scale projects and medium scale as well.  What we like to do is setup a outer page with navigation and an inside page that the client has control of by a control panel with FCK Editor or TinyMCE.

So essentially we have a wrapper page (in our case a MasterPage but in PHP you would use an include or a index.php with a query string to pull the content) and then we drop in HTML content from the database.

That database is populated by the client in their control panel.  FCK Editor allows them to upload images and manage links, etc.

For our bigger clients we get very specific in our control panel allowing them to add videos, PDF attachments, blog entries, FAQ content, etc.

Some examples we have are http://pspwllc.com and http://needsontime.com and http://nwacasa.org

Comment: Thanks very much! So I looked into the FCK Editor a little and saw that it's commonly used in Drupal. Can it be used outside Drupal as well? Would I just be able to make a static HTML/PHP page with an FCK Editor in there, and from there input text and images into a mySQL database? And then I would ultimately store all data, including images, text, PDFs, etc. in that database and extract it via PHP on the real website?

Comment: Yes, FCK Editor and TinyMCE can be used on any web site.  Yes you can create a static HTML page with FCK Editor.  You can also populate the images pop up in FCK Editor with Images from your database (you just have to update the Images plugin).  To your last question, yes, everything comes out of the database for us.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal can be bit complex at first but if you stick with the basic modules - it is great for website content management.You can write your own mini content management system - store text and images(MySQL blob format) in MySQL.It will be couple of PHP admin pages and a good render() function responsible for page rendering.

Comment: Thanks very much! It definitely is complicated at first, but I think I'm getting the hang of the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at wordpress, it is much easier than drupal. It is less powerful but it may serve your needs. You will NOT need to configure modules like FCKeditor, with it bcoz they come inbuilt. Anybody will be able to edit the content easily. Do note that wordpress is not just for blogs, you can create different kinds of websites with it. Another choice is Joomla, it is also simpler than drupal. But, wordpress is the simplest.